# Getting erros using passport-google-oauth20 InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile and Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm using passport strategies for different socialMedia logins and getting the following two errors

1. InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile
2. Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

   I have doubt there somewhere I have returned a callback or response so getting 2nd error but for 1st don't know reasons scope seems to be correct!

strategy code

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY,
  callbackURL: GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL
}, async (acessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  await User.findOne({ email: profile._json.email }, async (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("passport.config --> err", err);
     done(err, null);
    } else if (user) {
      if (user.socialType !== "GOOGLE" || user.socialType === null)
        done(`LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_WITH_${(user.socialType || "PASSWORD").toUpperCase()}`, false);
      else {
       done(null, user);
      }
    } else {
      // console.log(profile);
      const user = {
        email: profile._json.email,
        socialId: profile.id,
        socialType: "GOOGLE",
        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
        lastName: profile.name.familyName,
        isActive: profile._json.email_verified,
        isVerified: profile._json.email_verified,
        socialImageUrl: profile._json.picture,
        userType: "CUSTOMER"
      };
      const newUser = new User({ ...user });
      const newUserData = await newUser.save();
     done(null, newUserData);
    }
  });
}));
```

**route** code:

```
router.get('/auth/:socialType', customerCtrl.socialTypeLogin);

router.get('/auth/:socialType/callback', customerCtrl.socialTypeLoginCallback);
```

**controller** code:

```
const socialTypeLogin = async (req, res) => {
    await customerService.socialTypeLogin(req, res);
};

const socialTypeLoginCallback = async (req,res) => {
  await customerService.socialTypeLoginCallback(req,res);
};
```

**service** code:

```
const socialTypeLogin = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const socialType = (req.params.socialType || '').toLowerCase();
      const GOOGLE_SCOPE = ['email', 'profile'];
      const FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email'];
      let scope = [];
      if (socialType === 'google') {
        scope = GOOGLE_SCOPE;
      } else if (socialType === 'facebook') {
        scope = FACEBOOK_SCOPE;
      }
      let oauthOptions = { scope: scope};
      const { returnUrl } = req.query;
      if(returnUrl && returnUrl.trim().length !== 0) {
        oauthOptions['state'] =JSON.stringify({ returnUrl: returnUrl });
      }
      passport.authenticate(socialType, oauthOptions)(req, res);
    }
    catch (error) {

    }
}

/**
 * @param {string} socialType
 */

const socialTypeLoginCallback = async (req, res) => {
  const socialType = (req.params.socialType || '').toLowerCase();
  // return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      passport.authenticate(socialType, async (err, user) => {
        let webappRedirectURL = WEBAPP_LOGIN_URL;
        try {
          const state = req.query.state; 
          if(state) {
            const stateObj = JSON.parse(state);
            webappRedirectURL = stateObj.returnUrl;
          }
        } catch (err1) {
          console.log("customer.service --> parsing error",err1);
        }
        if (err || !user) {
          console.log("customer.service --> !user",err);
          res.render('oauth-redirect', {
            webappRedirectURL: webappRedirectURL,
            success: false,
            error: err,
            timerCounter: 5,
            accessToken: undefined
          });
        }
        else {
          console.log("customer.service --> Generating Token",user.generateJWT());
          res.render('oauth-redirect', {
            webappRedirectURL: webappRedirectURL,
            success: true,
            timerCounter: 5,
            accessToken: user.generateJWT(),
            error: undefined
          });
        }
      })(req, res);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log("customerService.js ==> socialTypeLoginCallback -->",error);
    }
};
```

**Thanks for help in advance!**
I have doubt there somewhere I have returned a callback or response so getting 2nd error but for 1st don't know reasons scope seems to be correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `socialTypeLogin`
add line

```
oauthOptions['session'] = false;
```